# Only the 1st letter is shown when php echo inner array

Tags: php, echo

The code I'm using .. (thanks to help I've received from here for me to get this far as a total novice!)

```
function readCSV($csvFile)
    {
        $line_of_text = [];
        $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
        //skip csv headers and blank lines
        fgetcsv($file_handle);
        fgetcsv($file_handle);
        fgetcsv($file_handle);  
        while (!feof($file_handle)) {
            $tmp = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

            if (isset($line_of_text[$tmp[0]])) {
                foreach ($tmp as $k => $v) {

                    if (array_key_exists($k, $line_of_text[$tmp[0]])) {
                        if (!is_array($line_of_text[$tmp[0]][$k])) {
                            $kVal = $line_of_text[$tmp[0]][$k];

                            $line_of_text[$tmp[0]][$k] = [];
                            $line_of_text[$tmp[0]][$k][] = $kVal;
                        }

                        $line_of_text[$tmp[0]][$k][] = $v;
                        $line_of_text[$tmp[0]][$k] = array_unique($line_of_text[$tmp[0]][$k]);
                        $line_of_text[$tmp[0]][$k] = array_filter($line_of_text[$tmp[0]][$k]);

                        if (count($line_of_text[$tmp[0]][$k]) == 1) {
                            $line_of_text[$tmp[0]][$k] = array_values($line_of_text[$tmp[0]][$k]);
                            $line_of_text[$tmp[0]][$k] = $line_of_text[$tmp[0]][$k][0];
                        }

                        if (empty($line_of_text[$tmp[0]][$k])) {
                            $line_of_text[$tmp[0]][$k] = null;
                        }

                    } else {
                        $line_of_text[$tmp[0]][$k] = null;
                    }
                }
                $line_of_text[$tmp[0]][0] = $tmp[0];

            } else {
                $line_of_text[$tmp[0]] = $tmp;
            }

        }

        fclose($file_handle);
        return array_filter(array_values($line_of_text));
    }

    // Set path to CSV file
    $csvFile = 'tmp_csv_store/my.csv';
    $csv = readCSV($csvFile);

//$csv is your array
foreach($csv as $key => $value){
 if(!array_key_exists(@$value[0],$arr)){
  $arr[@$value[0]] = [];
  }
  $arr[@$value[0]] = array_merge($arr[@$value[0]],$value);  
}
foreach($arr as $order)
{
    echo "Order number: " . $order["0"];
echo "<br>";
    foreach($order["21"] as $item)
    {
        echo "Item Name: " . $item["0"];
        echo "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

The result i'm getting is..

```
Order number: 110393
Item Name: D
Item Name: D

Order number: 110390
Item Name: D
Item Name: D
Item Name: D
```

When I was expecting..

```
Order number: 110393
Item Name: Desc1
Item Name: Desc2

Order number: 110390
Item Name: Desc2
Item Name: Desc4
Item Name: Desc10
```

I have read over several "only getting 1st letter" questions, tried adding ""s so [0] becomes ["0"]
and that didn't work? I can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: Also just noticed for items where there is only 1 (so no subarray when only 1) it does not get displayed at all, how do i handle this?

Comment: Is `$item` an array? Seems like it is a string do `var_dump($item)`.

Comment: You’re most likely looping over one dimension to many - you have a string value at that point, but it gets accessed with [0], and since that is valid syntax for accessing the individual characters (more correct: _bytes_) of a string value, you only get the first character shown …

Comment: `echo "Item Name: " . $item["0"];` -> `echo "Item Name: " . $item;` is probably the simple fix this needs already.

Comment: Just added an edit to the bottom of my OP which is probaby relivant, as sometimes its a subarray but sometimes its a single item (no sub array, just data)

Comment: echo "Item Name: " . $item["0"]; -> echo "Item Name: " . $item;  has made the full text now how for when they are an array but as prev mentioned sometime [21] may just be a value and not an array for when it only contains 1 item, how do I handle this so in either case it gets echo'd?

Comment: Did I get downvoted because of the edit? should I have started a new question for how to echo an array value that is sometimes multidimensional?

Comment: In such a situation, it is probably best if you _make_ the single value into an array first, so that you can then proceed with the same loop logic afterwards in either case. `if(!is_array($order["21"])) { $order["21"] = [ $order["21"] ]; }`